# POST a cross domain HTTP form from HTTPS page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, security, https

I'm trying to eliminate non-secure content errors on a site when it's using HTTPS.

I have one link that is actually a hidden form POSTing a specific search to a different HTTP website - they don't have HTTPS enabled.

This form submission does not contain any sensitive data, it's just a static search query, but it's causing the insecure content error when loading my site in HTTPS. Switching the form to HTTPS breaks it.

Any ideas how I can work around this? The best I can come up with a standard on-site link to a page that forces HTTP and putting the hidden form on there, but I'd rather not put the user through the extra click if it can be helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented my not quite perfect idea for a workaround. If nobody comes up with anything better I'll accept my own answer later.

I ended up using a standard hyperlink to send the user to a HTTP page and submitting the form there.

To keep this from seeming weird to the user I disguised the page as an external link warning:

---

The link you have selected to **somedomain.com** is external to the ourdomain.com website. OurCompanyName does not control **somedomain.com** and can not guarantee it's content and links.

### **Click here to continue >>>**